# Tracking down URLs of deleted videos in a youtube playlist

Tags: youtube, youtube-data-api

I've recently made a Python program using the Youtube api v3 where, given a playlist id, it fetches certain information from every video in the playlist. However, through both the output of this code and [this post on Google](https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/3876476?hl=en), it's pretty clear that information on videos that were either privated or deleted is not available through the Youtube api.

> Is there an alternative program or resource that I can use to extract information from these unavailable videos, in particular their video ids?

The only solution I can think of now is to access the HTML of the display Youtube and search through it for certain strings (like "[deleted video]") and to then extract the id corresponding to that string. But, I've never dealt with HTML and, if I understand HTML correctly, I'd have to load a new page for every 50 videos in the playlist, which for playlists with thousands of videos, becomes rather inefficient and laborious.

I was hoping to use something like PyTube, but that couldn't handle unavailable videos either.

---

#### Edit

Here is the code that extracts the video ids:

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

api_key = "AI~~~" #get from yt (private key)
yt = build("youtube", "v3", developerKey = api_key)

plst_id = "PLorw3mfu-J0ipF4Ss0XgR8IxcwP-JzNKC" #unique yt playlist id
plst_req = yt.playlistItems().list( #request for info from yt api
    part = "contentDetails",
    playlistId = plst_id,
    maxResults = 50
)

plst = plst_req.execute()

vid_ids = [] #available video ids taken from current playlist
for vid in plst['items']:
    vid_ids.append(vid['contentDetails']['videoId'])

print(vid_ids)
print(plst['pageInfo']['totalResults'])
```

The first line printed contains the video ids of every *available* video in the playlist. The second line printed gives the number of videos in the playlist, including available and unavailable ones.

The playlist used in the code above is given [here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLorw3mfu-J0ipF4Ss0XgR8IxcwP-JzNKC). It contains 10 total videos, of which one of them is unavailable.

In this case, the output is (with a valid api key)

```
['bv_cEeDlop0', 'mRKTOZmX2cE', '5ACvKdx1nns', 'wSNhP8b_Avo', 's56cHgokPlE', 'E4IHMWnQiMw', 'sCDkPShADSc', 'EVwgeUVVDYU', 'Z8Mqw0b9ADs']
10
```

Youtube still treats unavailable videos as an element of the playlist, but does not give out it's video id. In this particular instance, the video id of the unavailable video is "t83zUmjr05I", which is not hard to find manually: copy the link address of the deleted video and extract the part after the "v=".

But, on a larger scale manual extraction becomes tedious.

Comment: Can you add examples of deleted videos in the playlist you're checking and the code you're using? - *this info should be in your question* - If the info is not available neither by YouTube API or its website, I doubt there's a way to get information of such videos - unless you have access somehow to any database that has saved the info of those videos before been deleted or made private. I haven't tried, but, search on internet if such sites exists *(I mean, websites that manage database of YouTube videos)*.

Comment: Added more info on the code I used

Answer (score 0):

Here's a permanent fix to that!
You can try tube_dl.

```
pip install tube_dl
```

It uses modular approach and is up to date

More about this can be found at : https://github.com/shekharchander/tube_dl/

Maybe, the playlist module can help you with that. It uses regex to grab all video IDs not JSON. Please let me know if the problem is fixed or not, I will update module accordingly.

### Edit

Here's the working code

```
from tube_dl import Playlist
p = Playlist('https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLorw3mfu-J0ipF4Ss0XgR8IxcwP-JzNKC').videos
print(p)
```